# detect sound in a webview android java

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a webview with a web with a video. I need to detect when that video starts. it occurs to me to detect if the webview is emitting sound. Does anyone know how to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The video element has a play event:

```
const video = document.querySelector('video');

video.addEventListener('play', (event) => {
  console.log('The Boolean paused property is now false. Either the ' +
  'play() method was called or the autoplay attribute was toggled.');
});
```

source: MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play_event